# How to calculate nonlinearity/linearity of an array which contains distance between points?

Tags: linear-algebra, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system

There is an array which contains points as shown below;

```
[ -0.0249795, -0.00442094, -0.00397789, -0.00390947, -0.00384182, -0.0037756, -0.00371057, 0.00180882, 0.00251853, 0.00239539, 0.00244367, 0.00249255, 0.00254166, 0.00259185, 0.0116467, 0.0155782, 0.016471 ]
```

First of all, honestly, i don't know whether there is a measurement of nonlinearity or not. If there is, i would like to know what that's name is.

So how can i calculate the linearity or nonlinearity of this points distribution. I mean, after you draw a line from these points, how much will the line be linear and non-linear?

e.g. some line points, `p1= [1,-0.0249795], p2= [2, -0.00442094] ...`

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression . Doing a linear regression also gives you an error value which can be interpreted as 'how much do my points differ from a straight line'.

Comment: @GenericNickname Thanks for your reply. I will do it. Is there any way else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let your array be $a = (a_1,a_2,\ldots, a_n)$. Then you could use some formulas to compute lines through $a_1$ and $a_2$, $a_2$ and $a_3$, and so forth. By comparing each slope to the average, you get some kind of measurement of linearity. In numbers:

The slope of the line connecting $a_i$ and $a_{i+1}$ is

$$m_i = \frac{a_{i+1} - a_i}{i+1 - i} = a_{i+1} - a_i$$

Doing this you get $n-1$ slopes $m_1, \ldots, m_{n-1}$ and the average equals
$$m := \frac{m_1 +\ldots + m_{n-1}}{n-1} = \frac{a_n - a_1}{n-1}$$

Now you can compute how much all the $m_i$ differ from $m$
$$r = \sqrt{ \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} (m_i - m)^2}$$
Then $r = 0$ if and only if all points are on a straight line and $r > 0$ if they are not.

While this is quite easy to compute, I still encourage you to look at [linear regressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) and its error value since the method above is quite susceptible for errors: If all but one point lie on a straight line and the only bad one has a huge discrepancy, then the $r$ is still quite big although the points are 'close' to being on a straight line.

Answer (score 0):

The term "linear" is used somewhat differently than what one would first expect, as it is not so much about whether or not a function looks like a straight line, but more about how nicely it behaves when doing certain things to it. What you are looking for is probably *linear regression*, where you (or your computer) draw the straight line that best fits your data, that is, the line that *minimizes* the distance from it self to the data points.